# Jump on top of page after jquery ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am in the lower section of a long html page. I press a button that does an ajax call.
When the call to the server returns I want to "jump" or scroll up to the top of the page. How can I do this?
I tried:
`window.scrollTo(0,0)` and `$(window).scrollTop(0);` inside my JQuery function but neither works.
**Note**:
I do **not** need animation
I do **not** need the user to press any a href link

Comment: If this doesn't work then something is wrong with your code. As this should work. Can you show code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
```

Put this inside the success function .

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('html').scrollTop(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
$(window).scrollTop(0);
```

Or

```
$(document).scrollTop(0);
```

OR

```
$(document).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0); // scrolls without animation
```